# Excluding jar files from GWTP war file

Tags: gwt-platform, gwtp

Currently I am working on a GWTP application. While deploying to application server I remove all the jar files from the application.war file and then I push the war to webapps. I have put all the jars in the application server lib directory. The application works fine. I just have to know, can we remove all the jars from WEB-INF/lib of war file. Is this approach right? please let me know.
And also I have another question. I manually remove the jar files from the created war file which got created using ant. Please give me examples to automatically remove jars from build.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I see only disadvantages from this approach:

- If you want to run another application on your server which use an other version of a library, you can't.
- Each time you update a jar in you dev environment, you will need to manually copy it to your server lib/ directory instead of having it automatically packaged.

Why having them in WEB-INF/lib bothers you?

Comment: Main problem of including jar files in WEB-INF/lib, war file size increases and it takes a huge time to upload war file in server.